# MQTT on Zynq running Petalinux

Tags: embedded-linux, zynq, petalinux

I have a MicroZed board with some custom logic, and running Petalinux. I am getting some data from the logic through Petalinux, which I want to push to the internet. It is a sort of an IoT device. Is there any way to compile MQTT (Paho MQTT C Client for example) for petalinux 2015.2?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the embedded C version of Paho MQTT to compile using linux network libraries, and it works.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could elaborate or clarify what you did to succeed, We are struggling to compile it  under pentalinux for the past few days.